# Magento 2 : Change product price when enter value in custom textbox

Tags: magento2, product, price

I added one custom textbox in product view page. Now, I want to do like when add any text it should be calculate price and update product price.

and when I leave empty textbox it should be restore by default product price.

In Image, It's custom options. But, I want to do with custom textbox without custom options.

How to do that?

Please help me.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you can do custom jquery but price change only on product page and working only product page not cart page,checkout page